# changing the location of C# code files along with db

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an application written in c# [WPF] which involves lot of communication with several databases, hence i used SQL server 2008. Now i need to move the code files along with the database files to another system(it doesn't have sql server installed). Once i run the applications exe , it gets struck as it is not able to retrieve data from .mdf file.

Is it possible to access sql server 2008 installed in my system through a network ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple . I think you are using .mdf files as your database. Instead of it use .sdf as the database format which is mostly used in mobile development. There are lots of .mdf to .sdf converter available in the net.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the second system access the SQL Server of the first system.

You need to modify the connection string so that it accesses a server on a remote machine, and make sure the proper authentication mechanism is used. If both machines are on the same Winodws domain, it's going to be fairly simple.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this..?